# ng-show doesn't reveal instantly but on page change?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have this code to show loading message.

```
<ion-view title="Rooms">
<ion-content>
    <ion-list ng-show="rooms">
        <ion-item class="item-icon-left" ng-repeat="room in rooms" type="item-text-wrap" ng-click="openChatRoom(room.id)">
            <i class="icon {{room.icon}}"></i>
            <h2>{{room.name}}</h2>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-list ng-hide="rooms.length">
        <ion-item class="textCenter">
            <i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i> Loading Rooms
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

What it does now is just showing "loading Rooms" for awhile and nothing shows up. 
But when I change page and return to this page again, items in ng-show just shows up and never show "loading Rooms" again. 
So why this ng-show doesn't reveal instantly? Below are its controllers

```
.controller('RoomsCtrl', function($scope, Rooms, Chats, $state, $ionicModal) {
    //console.log("Rooms Controller initialized");
    $scope.rooms = Rooms.all();
    console.log($scope.rooms);
    $scope.openChatRoom = function (roomId) {
        $state.go('app.chat', {
            roomId: roomId
        });
    };  
})
.factory('Rooms', function ($firebase) {
    // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
    var ref = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);
    var rooms = $firebase(ref.child('rooms')).$asArray();

    return {
        all: function () {
            return rooms;
        },
        get: function (roomId) {
            // Simple index lookup
            return rooms.$getRecord(roomId);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `ng-show="rooms.length"`? Basically your `ng-show` and `ng-hide` should have the same expression to never display both

Comment: Also does this `$firebase` actually returns an array or a promise? (is it synchronous code or calls a server or something?)

Comment: @floribon oh it works instantly when I change to `ng-show="rooms.length"`, thanks.